# Do I have to encrypt SecureString when persisting to disk?

Tags: c#, securestring

For a C# console app, I need to persist a password in the application settings but when I create a setting of type `System.Security.SecureString` the setting itself is removed from the plain-text config file. Since I can't see the raw value anymore I can't validate whether or not the data is still encrypted when saved.

Is `SecureString` the best approach or should I use `ProtectedData` to simply encrypt the string?

--EDIT--
Here is the test code that I used to validate that a `SecureString` can be persisted.

```
        [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public global::System.Security.SecureString Password
        {
            get
            {
                return ((global::System.Security.SecureString)(this["Password"]));
            }
            set { this["Password"] = value; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PersistPassword("A-Test-Password");
            Console.WriteLine(ReadPassword());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void PersistPassword(string Password)
        {
            SecureString ss = new SecureString();
            Password.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(ss.AppendChar);
            Settings.Default.Password = ss;
        }

        static string ReadPassword()
        {
            SecureString ss = Settings.Default.Password;
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode(ss);
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr);
        }
```

Comment: I don't think that will work at all.

Comment: You can use `BCrypt` to hash your password. Secure string is just a class and it doesn't allow you to work with a string actually you can only work with it using `Marshal` and `Pointer`

Comment: If you would like to save the password in the app.config and use it from the application, I think you can do it. If so, please give a note, I will add some sample code.

Comment: I can successfully persist and read a SecureString in a settings file and since it's doesn't give an exception I can only assume it's remaining encrypted (or at least serialized).

Comment: [The SecureString never actually gets saved to disk](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4557d9b-6e7d-4695-bfd0-a22a08e06160/). It reads back from within the same process because it's still in memory, but if you exit and restart, you'll find that the string is empty.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, you're exactly right! I never exited the program and when I tested it, sure enough, the value was null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot persist data that is encrypted with **SecureString**. The key is held in memory, and only lasts as long as your program is alive. SecureString is a wrapper around the native [**CryptProtectMemory**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectmemory) function.

If you need you need the encrypted data to be persistable (for longer than your program exists), you need the **Data Protection API** (DPAPI), and it's [**CryptProtectData**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata) function - which is exposed to C# users through the **ProtectedData** class.

**SecureString** has the advantage of being ephemeral; useful for:

- passwords
- credit card numbers
- Social Insurance numbers

while they are being used by your program - and then deleted.

The DPAPI is better for long-term storage. But beware the protection levels, and you choose the one that is appropriate for what you need:

- only decryptable by me
- only decryptable on this PC
- only decryptable by anyone on the domain

If you need encryption that can survive transport to different sites or different domains: CryptProtectData is not for you.

## Four levels

- **CryptProtectMemory** (SecureString in .NET): only useful in memory of your process
- **CryptProtectData** (ProtectedData in .NET): encrypts a blob of data, and you can store it anywhere you like (memory, registry, hard disk) - but you have to store it yourself.
- **CredWrite:** encrypts a password using **CryptProtectData**, and stores it for you in the Windows Password Vault (Start → Credential Manager)
- **CredUIPromptForCredentials**/**CredUIConfirmCredentials**: prompt the user for a password, encrypt it, and saves it in the Password Vault (Start → Credential Manager) using **CredWrite**

Comment: Whilst this for C#, I'm not sure this is really true as SecureString's use in PowerShell can be dumped, in it's encrypted form, and stored persistently.

Answer (score 1):

As states in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396),

> The value of an instance of SecureString is automatically protected using a mechanism supported by the underlying platform when the instance is initialized or when the value is modified.

If you want to provide the mechanism to keep it readonly once the password in store in securestring then you can invoke the method `MarkAsReadonly()` on it.

For persistence purpose you can also Hash the `SecureString` and create a salt for it. You can retreive the salt for later use e.g. comparison pupose. Check out [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93111/hashing-a-securestring-using-cryptography-next-generation) code snippet which is using the salt over `Securestring`.